# Which Should i use for date,time,email in servlet?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets

In servlet we use for text data

```
String uname=request.getParameter("uname");
```

For numeric data we use

```
int contact=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact"));
```

Which should i use for email,date and time in servlet?

Actually I'm using HTML5 where I use email as

```
<input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" required>
```

Date as

```
<input type="date" id="dateBirthday" name="birthday" required>
```

Time as

```
<input type="date" id="dateBirthday" name="birthday" required>
```

So which should i use in servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servlet api does not provide any special way of getting date and email. getParameter will always get you a `String` value.  It is up to you how you want to treat it.

For date you can work with raw String data or you may want ot parse it in to a `Date` object as per your convinence.  But make sure you know the Date pattern before parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

In servlet, the request.getParameter("param") will be a String. So you ca use:

```
String txtEmail=request.getParameter("email");
String dateBirthday=request.getParameter("birthday");
```

and depending on your next uses of your variables, you can do conversions as you did for the int variable.

Comment: Sir i need an answer again.you used                                                   String  txtEmail=request.getParameter("txtEmail");because id="txtEmail".but if i use name instead of id.will it be any problem?i mean if i use String email=request.getParameter("email");will it be any error??

Comment: in fact, you should use the name value in the getParameter() method. However if you had omitted the name property, you just use the id; they will be equal. A mistake from my part see my edit